# TeX Live tools on command line unreferenced

Tags: installing, texlive

I've just installed TeX Live 2013 from [tug.org](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)

The installation was pretty long because my connection is slow and It had to download all the files.

My problem is I think I did the wrong way, I've installed the update of TeX Live but I didn't uninstall TeX Live 2009 just before, I guess this is not really a big problem because the installation directory is different from 2009 and 2013 (*/usr/share/texmf/* and */usr/local/texlive/2013/*) But now I seem not able to use the tools properly (TeXworks can't find my Live distro and I can't even use the binaries from the command line).

I uninstalled TeX Live 2009 after the installation of the 2013, How can I tell the system to include the binaries of the TeX live bundle, do I have to go through all that manually ?

I'm using ubuntu

Comment: Add these lines to the your `.profile` file: `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux:$PATH 
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH`. Log-out and then log-in once again.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks! I've changed some information about the path but now It works

Answer (score 5):

Add the followwing lines to your `.profile` file:

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux:$PATH 
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH 
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH
```

Log-out and then log-in once again.